# Display element only when transition is finished

Tags: html, css

When `nav-toggle` is checked sidebar reduces width and `span` is not displayed. When `nav-toggle` is unchecked it all comes back, but span displays the moment `nav-toggle` is unchecked and takes vertical space until sidebar is wide enough.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 345px;
  transition: width 300ms;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+.sidebar {
  width: 70px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+.sidebar li a span:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="nav-toggle">
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-brand">
    <h2><span class="lab la-accusoft"></span> <span>Acusoft</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="active"><span class="las la-igloo"></span>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><span class="las la-users"></span>
          <span>Customers</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to delay displaying 'span' until after transition is finished or sidebar is wide enough.

Comment: Are you looking for a "css only" solution, or do you have the ability to add some JavaScript/jQuery into this project?

Comment: @BrandonTrecki It's preferable to use on;y css, but I don't mind adding JS.

Comment: Ok, take a look at my answer it has no JS anyways but you could definitely use that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the `display: none` into an `opacity: 0`, and have another transition with a `transition-delay`

This may not be an exact answer but could help you in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/9uqgmnfk/16/

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #eee;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  height: 50vh;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 5%;
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
}


.sidebar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li a span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
  transition-delay: 1.25s;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+.sidebar li a span:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">

<label class="nav-toggle-label" for="nav-toggle">Toggle</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="nav-toggle">
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-brand">
    <h2><span class="lab la-accusoft"></span> <span>Acusoft</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="active"><span class="las la-igloo"></span>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><span class="las la-users"></span>
          <span>Customers</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<main class="main-content" role="main">
  <h2>
  Main Content
  </h2>
</main>

</div>
```